# Terminal opens with "-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory"

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, homebrew, python

I tried to install OpenCV through Homebrew by following the steps given in http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/05/macos-install-opencv-3-and-python-3-5/ but after installing virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper I updated the path as given. When I source it I get the following

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory
```

I have macOS Sierra 10.12.6, Xcode 8.3.3.

Then I closed the Terminal and reopened it. Since then whenever I open the Terminal I see the same line in the second line of the terminal. I made a small change and installed virtualenv using

```
pip --user install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
```

[image]

Comment: Whaty does `which pip` show?

Comment: In a vanilla Sierra & homebrew & brew installed python 3, pip doesn't exist! Some steps in the how-to aren't necessary (`export path`) or won't work (`pip ...`).

Comment: Ys-MacBook-Air:~ hareentej22$ which python                                                  
/usr/bin/python
Ys-MacBook-Air:~ hareentej22$ which pip
Ys-MacBook-Air:~ hareentej22$ which pip2
/usr/local/bin/pip2
Ys-MacBook-Air:~ hareentej22$

Comment: its showing nothing.

Comment: @klanomath sorry sir i could'nt understand you . but i followed trying to install opencv with miniconda by refering this [tutorial](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2016/11/29/install-opencv-3-with-python-3-on-macos/) . after running the code i get the following error                          `File "demo1.py", line 3
    print("OpenCV version:")
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent`

Comment: @hareentej The how-to you are following is using `pip ...`. If the vanilla Sierra & brew python3 don't contain/install *pip*, the how-to relies on software installed previously and/or on an older system. Then the how-to for Sierra is incomplete (it's missing the step to install pip) and/or wasn't tested thoroughly.

Comment: which pip should i install ?? pip or pip2 or pip3 ?

Comment: Flagged: Off-topic: questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved.

Comment: @Mark it shows      /usr/local/bin/pip   . i just realised i have some problem in `which python ` path . u can refer my answer for in detail  .

Answer (score 1):

This is a common stumbling block when editing shell files.

I would remove any .bashrc and .bash_profile entries you know you don't need and then get a package manager to help you with managing the bash requirements. There is step by step help and many questions here on how to get homebrew set up.

- [Where can I download OpenCV for macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298693/where-can-i-download-opencv-for-macos)
- https://docs.brew.sh/Installation.html

The benefits of homebrew is it makes some decisions about where alternative versions of python and packages live and you can not have to manage those as the software changes.

Comment: yes after a little bit of research i got to know that installing opencv via homebrew got so many benifits . and then i followed and reached some steps [in this link](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/11/28/macos-install-opencv-3-and-python-2-7/) . but when i run the command `brew linkapps python' i only get 2 apps linked . and also even though i set the path as PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH   in bash profile , when i run command `which python` i get `/usr/bin/python`

Answer (score -2):

i solved it by just emptying the bash_profile and save an empty bash_profile . then after you wont see that second line whenever you open the terminal .